# SimpleIdentifiableResourceAssembler cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, maven-dependency

I am following this tutorial: [Spring HATEOAS - Basic Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas-examples/tree/master/basics)

And I have a spring boot project with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The tutorial shows that Spring HATEOAS provides SimpleIdentifiableResourceAssembler as the simplest mechanism to perform conversions.

The problem is that I cannot resolve the class "SimpleIdentifiableResourceAssembler" from the org.springframework.hateoas packages .. It throws an `SimpleIdentifiableResourceAssembler cannot be resolved to a type`

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's sort of late but for future (and confused) developers: The answer is simply that the Class

`SimpleIdentifiableResourceAssembler`

has not been added to the Repo so far. You have to implement the functionality on your own (see [Github issue for this question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas-examples/issues/11))

Answer (score 1):

HATEOAS dependency is added in:

[image]

But this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the HATEOAS dependency in your project.

Add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: spring-hateoas it's added, but this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I use `RepresentationModelAssembler` it is part of

```
org.springframework.hateoas.server.RepresentationModelAssembler;
```

**example:**

```
@Component
public class AccountModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<AccountResponse, EntityModel<AccountResponse>> {

  @Override
  public @NonNull CollectionModel<EntityModel<AccountResponse>> toCollectionModel(@NonNull Iterable<? extends AccountResponse> entities) {
    return RepresentationModelAssembler.super.toCollectionModel(entities);
  }

  
  @Override
  public @NonNull EntityModel<AccountResponse> toModel(@NonNull AccountResponse entity) {
    // Do your mapping and link generation here.
  }
}
```

And `AccountResponse` is like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record AccountResponse(
    Integer id,
    String code,
    String name,
    String description,
    AccountTypeEnum type
) {
}
```